# How to declare a global variable?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

This is a very simple question, I am getting the day of a week using a snippet

```
 if let weekday = getDayOfWeek("2017-05-01") {
        print(weekday)
    } else {
        print("bad input")
    }


func getDayOfWeek(_ today:String) -> Int? {
    let formatter  = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    guard let todayDate = formatter.date(from: today) else { return nil }
    let myCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let weekDay = myCalendar.component(.weekday, from: todayDate)
    return weekDay
}
```

I need to create "weekday" as global variable can any one help.

What I did is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
var weekday = NSInteger()
}
```

I am getting some error in snippet while declaring as above.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: value of optional type int..

Comment: can you screenshot error message?

Comment: Please show us what type of error you got.

Comment: Use this var weekday = Int(), may be this will help

Comment: Do you really mean global?

You appear to be asking for a class-level declaration, which would not be accessible from second ViewController.  If you actually need a global variable, you should have a look for singleton examples, or passing data between controllers using segues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `currentWeekDay` type to `Int`.

```
var weekday = Int()
```

Now access this instance property with `if let`.

```
if let weekday = getDayOfWeek("2017-05-01") {
    //weekday has block scope and available only with in this if block
    self.weekday = weekday
} else {
    print("bad input")
}
```

**Edit:** Set `timezone` to get correct weekday

```
func getDayOfWeek(_ today:String) -> Int? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
    guard let todayDate = formatter.date(from: today) else { return nil }
    let myCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let weekDay = myCalendar.component(.weekday, from: todayDate)
    return weekDay 
}
```

Comment: Niarav not is awson working good, Why we should declare like this

Comment: why we should declare self.weekday = weekday

Comment: @NiravD Maybe you should make it clearer that the weekday is in-fact a global variable, because right not it looks like it's in the same scope as the if-let statement (which should be in a func).

Comment: @BenjaminLowry Change the instance property name to remove the confusion.

Comment: @NiravD now i got it

Comment: @Arun Thats great mate :)

Comment: @NiravD i Have to say If i did like this  i am geting wrong day of week

Comment: @Arun My answer is correct you just need to show what is wrong and what is not working because this question not ask for get correct week day it is ask to access the value of weekday outside the if block also

Comment: nirav. s u r correct but output that means the day of week I am getting varies from your altered code , it was incremented by one count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134466/discussion-between-arun-and-nirav-d).